# Qt connect() without QObject or slots

Tags: c++, qt

I know what I am trying to achieve is possible, because I can do it with a lambda expression and I have done it before (Few months ago I just don't remember the syntax). Basically, I want to connect a function to a timer/button/etc. to facilitate the workings of an event.

Here is my working code:

```
connect( &renderTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [ = ]() {
        onTimerUpdate();
    } );
```

That uses a lambda to connect to the slot. I want to just reference the function itself instead of using a lambda expression. I have tried inserting the method `onTimerUpdate()` and `&onTimerUpdate` none of which work. I don't want to use `QObject` or any of it's pre-generated bullcrap — nor do I want to define slots within my class. I want to, quite simply, connect it directly to my function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the format when connecting to a member function:

```
QObject::connect(&renderTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ArclightGLWidget::onTimerUpdate);
```

This is the format when connecting to a free funciton (same for lambda)

```
QObject::connect(&renderTimer, &QTimer::timeout, onTimerUpdate);
```

And this is the format when connecting to a static member function:

```
QObject::connect(&renderTimer, &QTimer::timeout, SomeType::onTimerUpdate);
```

Comment: @Krythic I assumed it was a free function, see my edit.

Comment: Will you also update your answer showing the free-function declaration so it can assist someone in the future? I will accept you as the answer in 2 minutes(Required wait).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this call is being made inside the class of which `onTimerUpdate` is a method. If so you can call:

```
connect(&renderTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &foo::onTimerUpdate);
```

This is preferable to the lambda because Qt will manage the connection and you will also be able to call `sender()` in the `slot`.

However if you are within the class in which `onTimerUpdate` is a method you can also use the lambda exactly as you have put in the question:

```
connect( &renderTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){onTimerUpdate();} );
```